# editing spring xml source with eclipse/sts - missing "mark occurrences" and "jump to bean in another file"?

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm working with Eclipse/STS and editing spring bean definition XMLs with the "Source" editor, as I dislike the GUI editors. I'm missing these features:

- mark occurrences - highlight all occurrences of the word I'm standing on (the same as in the java editor)
- Jump to bean (with F3 or ctrl-click), if its defined in another spring XML file

Am I missing a plugin? Should I work with the GUI editors?

Thanks, Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jump to bean with F3 should work, given the project is configured properly. That is:

- the project holding the Context XML definitions needs the "spring project nature"
- all the XML config files need to be announced for STS: in the project properties, use the "Spring" tab and from there "beans support" and add all config files. (This results in entries in your /.settings/.springBeans, which can be shared via SCM with the other team members)
- all prerequisite projects providing Java classes for those beans need to be declared as project dependencies, in case you're working with a multi module project.

Besides that, the "Spring Beans references search" is quite helpful: Place the cursor on a bean name and hit CTRL-SHIFT-g to get an outline of all references to this bean name (including the Java class and the bean definition in XML)

Comment: thanks Ichthyo, however jumping between beans from different xml definition files doesn't work for me on juno with the STS plugin, when I import "classpath:myfile". It only works when the import is without the classpath prefix. accepting anyway...